# Variable $u does not work when put into mysql_select_db

Tags: php, sql, get

I am facing this issue. Appreciate any advices.

I have a file called home.php. This home.php will get data from a url parameter called user.

### home.php

```
$u = $GET_["user"];
include('config.php');
```

Whenever ppl entered www.mydomain.com/index.php?user=hello, the text "hello" will be captured and put into variable $u.

I have a database called "hello" for that specific user. In the config.php i will do sql connection to the database using the following code.

### Config.php

```
define('DB_NAME', $u); 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'admin');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '123456');

$db = DB::getInstance();
//connect to database
$db->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
```

### Database connection class

```
function connect($host, $username, $password, $database) {
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Server connexion not possible.');
    mysql_select_db($database) or die('Database connexion not possible.');
}
```

Above are all code snippets.

My issue is i keep getting Database connexion not possible error. I believe everything is logically correct. To debug this, whenever i replaced  define('DB_NAME', $u); with  define('DB_NAME', "Hello"); -> it works. It seems that i cannot dynamically use the value from $u.

thnk all. help appreciated.

Comment: It's `$_GET["user"]`, not `$GET_["user"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to use `$_GET` - there is no such thing as `$GET_`

```
$u = $_GET["user"]
```

Comment: Hi. i am using $_GET (its a typo in stackoverflow, not in my app);

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_GET["user"]` instead of `$GET_["user"]`.

More documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Hi. i am using $_GET (its a typo in stackoverflow, not in my app